# Powershell to add reg key

Tags: powershell, registry, regedit

I have a Powershell script that "builds" a PC from the basic Windows operating system on up (Windows 7 Pro - will be converted to 10 next year).  I have a number of reg keys that get added when running this script and they all work fine, no problems.

I am having to add a new reg key which turns off Remote Desktop Services.  I can do it at the cmd line with

`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

which works fine and dandy.  So now I need to add this same key via a Powershell script and I can't get it to work.  What I have is

`New-Item -Path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' -Name fDenyTSConnections -Value 1 | Out-File $log -append`

and when I run that, something pops up that reads

`Type:`

So I assumed it is asking for a type.  But if I add PropertyType as below

`New-Item -Path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' -Name fDenyTSConnections -PropertyType DWORD -Value 1 | Out-File $log -append`

it gives an error.  I've researched at several forums online and nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think `New-Item` doesn't have a `-PropertyType`... I think that's `New-ItemProperty`

Comment: @techguy1029 - Then what is the "Type: " prompt that keeps popping up?

Comment: that might be the `ItemType` meaning Powershell wants to know if the `New-Item` is a file or directory

Answer (score 8):

You cannot create a registry key with properties at the same time.  You need to do one, then the other:

```
$path = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server'

$key = try {
    Get-Item -Path $path -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    New-Item -Path $path -Force
}

New-ItemProperty -Path $key.PSPath -Name fDenyTSConnections -Value 1
```

Comment: It might be better to `Test-Path -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server"` first, and only do the `New-Item` if the `Test-Path` fails - otherwise, you're 'blowing away' all of the TS settings.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin really?  in the filesystem provider, I noticed it's not destructive for existing items.  Wasn't aware that isn't the case with the registry provider.

Comment: I've seen inconsistent behavior in the registry; even where I "know" that it doesn't affect extant items in a provider, I consider it 'best practice' to test-and-create rather than just create-forcibly.

Comment: Thanks! This exactly help to solve my problem.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin What if overwriting (in case a key exists) is the goal? Would deleting it first be safe? Or is there an overwrite flag?

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 - Delete-then-recreate would generally be safe for _properties_ (and is arguably a 'best practice'). For _keys_ (represented as folders in RegEdit), you'd have to consider whether you need to preserve extant properties.

Answer (score 1):

I always create Registry Keys/Values like this:

```
# Set the location to the registry
Set-Location -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft'

# Create a new Key
Get-Item -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft' | New-Item -Name 'W10MigInfo\Diskspace Info' -Force

# Create new items with values
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\W10MigInfo\Diskspace Info' -Name 'usedDiskspaceCDrive' -Value "$usedDiskspaceCDrive" -PropertyType String -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\W10MigInfo\Diskspace Info' -Name 'usedDiskSpaceDDrive' -Value "$usedDiskspaceDDrive" -PropertyType String -Force

# Get out of the Registry
Pop-Location
```

Answer (score 0):

What I finally tested and got working was:

`cmd /c 'reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f' | Out-File $log -append`

I realize that's going around the Powershell option, but it's what I got to work for now.  Curious to see what I'm missing in the Powershell command, though.

Answer (score 0):

Error is probably in first command syntax "New-Item -Path"
Correct is "New-ItemProperty -Path"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-entries?view=powershell-7.2#creating-new-registry-entries

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).