# reg add in powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

i need help to use these registry to be be scripted over to powershell language. Anyone how can help me?

reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /v "Helvetica LT Bold (TrueType)" /t REG_SZ /d HelveticaBold.ttf /f

As I'm quite a beginner in powershell, I've tried to search around here and on the web but can't find any ways to solve it.

Comment: Try these:  [Example 1: Add a registry entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.3#example-1-add-a-registry-entry)  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=beginner+add+registry+values+using+powershell)  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/how-to-update-or-add-a-registry-key-value-with-powershell/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell to add reg key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205772/powershell-to-add-reg-key)